# How to show that a graph is not hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory

How can i prove  that a graph that has 1 vertex adjacent with  3 other vertexes that have 2 neighbours each  is not a hamiltonian graph ? Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ be a vertex, $u,v,w$ neighbours with degree $2$. The hamilton cycle must
 contain the edges $a-u$,$a-v$ and $a-w$ (if a vertex has degree $2$, both edges 
 from this vertex must be in a hamilton cycle). At the other hand, the hamilton
 cycle cannot contain more than $2$ edges from a vertex.

So we get a contradiction.